# Injected PasswordHash always throws null pointer when initializing with parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

When initializing an injected PasswordHash instance with parameters, a null pointer exception is always thrown.

Using several different examples online, I always get the same result.  Here is the most recent example I followed: https://medium.com/@swhp/explore-hash-feature-on-java-ee-security-jsr-375-soteria-7fe3b1953785 .
The IDE says the injected Pbkd2PasswordHash has an "Unsatisfied Dependency: no bean matches the injection point".  This makes sense, as it is an interface and I am not creating a new class with that interface.  However, all of the examples I've seen online inject this class without implementing it.

I am able to avoid the null pointer if I implement the PasswordHash  or PBkdf2PasswordHash interface and override the methods, but this defeats the purpose of passing in the parameters with the specific iterations, algorithim, salt size, and/or key size values.

```
@Inject
Pbkdf2PasswordHash pbkdfHash;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Iterations", "3072");
    parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Algorithm", "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
    parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.KeySizeBytes", "64");
    parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.SaltSizeBytes", "64");

    this.pbkdfHash.initialize(parameters);
}
```

I expect that when I initialize the injected PasswordHash with parameters, the instance will automatically hash the text passed in.  Because it seems I am not injecting any bean and I'm just injecting an interface, it only returns a null pointer when the instance is initialized.

Comment: all the examples have *__A__* class on the classpath that implements the interface and is found to an eligeable bean according to the cdi specs

Comment: And according to your title, `System.out.println(this.pbkdfHash.toString())` works... it does not does it? Effectively you most likely only have an api on the classpath and not an implementation. So you are either not running on a java-ee8 certified server (e.g. a java-ee7 one) or are running a servlet container and did not include an implementation yourself or have some beans.xml misconfiguration or...

Comment: For the examples I'm looking at, they are injecting Pbkdf2PasswordHash, which is an interface.  Does this not contradict what you are saying?  Also, if I am implementing that interface and overriding the hash and verify hash methods (which is necessary if implementing), what would be the point of initializing the instance with the parameters hash map, as it would be ignored by my overriding the methods.

Comment: Printing the hash to string does not work for me, as the instance is just null.  I am using Wildfly-15.0.1.Final.

Comment: No, it does not... ALL interfaces need a real implementation to be effectively usefull (you cannot instantiate an interface). And I'm not saying YOU should implement the interface, not at all. But you need *__An__* implementation on the classpath

Comment: And one that is according to the cdi 2.0 specs (am in the process of moving to java-ee8 myself, so I do not know all the cdi 2.0 details yet) so it might be beans.xml related

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje. I am in the process of checking my beans.xml, dependencies, etc. and hopefully will break some ground.

Comment: also check if you (by accident?) included the java security api in your project (it should not be, it should be provided)

Comment: Quickly browsing the spec, it doesn't seem to say that implementation has to provide an injectable bean for type `Pbkdf2PasswordHash`. That means it can be impl-specific. Soteria, which those articles refer to, actually has it as a bean, which can be seen from their code [here](https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/soteria/identitystores/hash/Pbkdf2PasswordHashImpl.java#L58). Whereas Keycloak, as another impl, seems to have factory, but no CDI bean, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/credential/hash/Pbkdf2Sha256PasswordHashProviderFactory.java) to the Keycloak factory my quicksearch gave me. But like I said, they might be adding it automagically somewhere else as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One implementation is provided by Glassfish and Wildfly as Pbkdf2PasswordHashImpl. I needed to add wildfly-ee-security or org.glassfish.soteria:javax.security.enterprise to pull in this class.  I suspect the examples I was looking at were implementing the PasswordHash interface themselves without showing the bean.

Thanks to Siliarus for providing the link to Soteria implementation:
https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/soteria/identitystores/hash/Pbkdf2PasswordHashImpl.java

<strike>I am now running into build errors regarding the dependencies needed, but that is outside of the scope of this question.  If you are interested, there is already an open issue at:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/soteria/issues/193</strike>

Comment: _" I suspect the examples I was looking at were implementing the PasswordHash interface themselves without showing the bean."_ I seriously doubt this. Most likely they were running on an app server that had it already... The build errors are most likely the result of you mixing up impls.